# JSON web token vs session - how does authentication from multiple devises work in detail?

Tags: session, jwt

I have read a lot about json tokens vs session and still dont understand a few things.

1. benefit of using token is authentication across multiple devices.

   - Lets say user signs up on website, server generates session id, sends to client, client saves it in cookies or localstorage (so whenever user wants to log in again on website, client sends session id to server on each request, sever queries db and checks if its same id if yes sends response). Then same user, uses mobile app to log in, since session id is only stored inside computers browsers cookies/localstorage and not on mobile device or other computer,  how would the log in from either different computer or mobile device happen?The server would send a different session id to each device the user logs in and then there is some sort of array stored on the server with ALL the users session ids?!
   - I also read that its much simpler with tokens as they are stateless. I just dont understand how that is relevant when it comes to multiple devices. 
     I read that for each request server checks using same signature as it used when it issued the token, if its valid. Client needs to send that token to server though with each request. So isnt that the same - different computer never stored the token inside cookies/localstorage so how would that work?!Would server need to create a different token? If thats the case, I dont get the difference and why session is less benefitial then tokens when it comes to multiple devices!
   - Also, I read: "Session cookies only work across a single domain, or on its subdomains. If they try to go to a third party, browsers tend to disable them....that wont happen with tokens". I dont understand what it means and how its related to multiple devices, also why cookies are relevant as json tokes ARE usually ALSO stored in cookies as well as session id?!

Sorry if its maybe too basic, I just read so much about that and just dont understand the basics.

Answer (score 0):

there are some important differences between JWT and sessions.

1. Sessions are stored inside RAM of the server or a database to store where a user is or what he is doing. For example, you store the current page the user is working on.
2. BUT JWT is stateless. The server does not save the user state or his data to RAM or database. the server generates a key for the user including some important data for authentication(for example username, role, last access date) therefore the user must send his key with every request until his key expires and he must request for another one. Since the key only includes User Auth data, It can be used in every device(until it expires).

as you mentioned in mobile applications user gets multiple sessions so JWT mostly used in mobile or single-page applications. the user gets a key and state of user activity will be handled by mobile application.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you,I still wonder why jwt are considered beneficial for multiple devices over sessions? With sessions, user gets multiple sessions. With jwt user will have seperate jwt for each device, no? so whats the benefit?

Comment: a server observes each connection as a session, Therefore, for every device server creates a session(stored on server). But JWT is encrypted user data (considered self-contained). The server has not to save the user data and user can use that token in every device because it has everything needed for the server to auth. It somehow reduces the load on the server. but using whether JWT or session completely depends on the application.

Comment: "user can use that token in every device because " - so with jwt its only ONE token user uses on all devises? How is that possible - the server creates the jwt sends it without storing to lets say computer nr.1. then user logs in on computer nr.2 -the server cannot send same jwt to computer nr 2 as it doesnt store it, so wouldnt it have to create a new jwt?

Comment: Also, why with session, does server create new session for each device? since server stores the session id, why doesnt it just sends the same to each device after user successfully loggs in?